# Nice forms Causing clear form issue

Tags: jquery, niceforms

For some reason on my form when it clears the fields it resets the value of the dropdowns to '' but it does not show the actual text of the option? Any ideas why?

```
$(':input','#templatesForm')
.not(':submit, :button, :hidden, :reset')
.val('');
```

EDIT:

```
<select size="1" name="status" id="status">
<option value="">- Select -</option>
<?php
echo $statuses;
?>
</select>
```

Edit 2:

I don't know what is causing this issue whether it be nice forms or the jQuery form validation plugin or what because with the reset button clicked I know use this code:

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

I have a few dropdowns and with the form reset it resets the values of all form fields even the dropdown however the text of the dropdown remains the same as the user's last change. Does anyone know and solution to make the select refresh so that its initial option is the default option?

Edit 3:

Any ideas from anyone because I've been stumped on this for a few days now.

Edit 4:

Hoping I get someone that has atleast one idea!

Edit 5:

Here's a js fiddle that does what I"m talking about. It resets the value of the dropdown to 0 but does not change the text option back to the default of - Select -

http://jsfiddle.net/EwpXp/

Comment: Show your actual select tag with the options please. If you don't actually have an option with a value="" then it won't show it.

Comment: There you go. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Tested this out with a regular select box and it worked fine. Not sure what niceforms is, but if this method does not work then it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Hmm Maybe someone will know of a bug that deals with that.

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: There is a bug in templates.js - remove `NFDo('start');` at the beginning. It's called twice and generates double inputs all over this form

Comment: Which is odd because when I do and run it in my CMS I have to have it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've stripped Your fiddle of all additional scripts (validate and template) :

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/EwpXp/5/

next, I've patched reset function to work with niceforms select:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/EwpXp/7/

**How Does Niceforms Work?**

The idea is simple: since normal input fields (including radio buttons, checkboxes, textareas, etc) can only be styled to a small degree, they have to be hidden and their visual appearance replaced with similar working, new, fully customizable constructs. In theory, that doesn't sound really complicated. But from theory to practice there is a long way.

**How is select handled**

```
<div class="NFSelect" style="width: 80px; left: 140px; top: 77px; z-index: 999;">
    <img class="NFSelectLeft" src="img/0.png">
    <div class="NFSelectRight">- Select -</div>
    <div class="NFSelectTarget" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="NFSelectOptions">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="NFOptionActive">- Select -</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Active</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Inactive</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<select id="status" class="NFhidden" name="status" size="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="Active">Active</option>
    <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

When reset on form is triggered, all html inputs are reset, but Niceforms duplicate select with divs. So I've copied value from option into Niceforms div (after reset). My code:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    // reset form
    $(':input','#templatesForm')
    .not(':submit, :button, :hidden, :reset')
    .val('');
    // update select
    $('select').each(function(){
        var option = $('option:selected', this).html();
        var niceselect = $(this).parents('dd').find('.NFSelectRight');
        niceselect.html(option);
        $(this).parents('dd')
            .find('.NFSelectTarget a')
            .removeClass('NFOptionActive')
            .filter(':first').addClass('NFOptionActive');
    });
});
```

**edit**

after considering, there is also other way - you could reload Niceforms. But it has a price - form blinks

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    // reset form
    $(':input','#templatesForm')
    .not(':submit, :button, :hidden, :reset')
    .val('');
    // reload niceforms
    NFDo('stop');
    NFDo('start');
});
```

Comment: Will this work as well if I have more than one select on each page?

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the values, but not changing the selection, so obvoiusly the selection won't change on its own.
Consider something like:

```
$notElements = $('input[type="submit"], input[type="hidden"]', '#templatesForm');
$resetable = $('#templatesForm input').not($notElements);
$('input[type="reset"]').click(function() { $resetable.val(""); return false; });
```

Comment: Did you look at my last edit code because there's no select in there and with that I'm not sure how to use it.